# How do I publish folder which contains files like python or xml files over ROSTOPIC?

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi4

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I want to make a publisher that sends folders that contain files from the laptop and make subscriber in raspberry that save this folder in a specific raspberry pi directory.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, publishers and subscribers in ROS deal with topics of defined message types.
so, you can not publish files of different types with the same publisher.
but you can publish files of the same type in a folder with one publisher and subscribe to it.
for example, you can publish all the images in that folder under a specific topic and message type.
in the case of text files, you can send the content of the file as a string.
I hope this helps you.